# Chef: restart service on a windows node

Tags: chef-infra

I want to restart a service on a windows node.
I can write a recipe as below:

```
service 'w3svc' do
  action [:enable, :restart]
end
```

and from the workstation execute it on the remote node with push jobs.
But how can i know on the workstation whether the service was restarted successfully?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If a Chef resource fails in some way, it aborts the converge and exits the process with a non-zero status code. In turn, when a Push Jobs job fails you can see it in the API. Wire it all together :)